# How to configure blat using office365 setting

Tags: office365, zoho, blat

I am trying to configure mail sending using `BLAT`
I use office 365,but due to some configuration issue I am having the problem of 
the following error

```
Subject: Contents of file: message.txt
Login name is yyyaa@xxxaa.com
*** Error ***  The SMTP server does not like the sender name.
*** Error ***  Have you set your mail address correctly?
Error: Connection to server was dropped.
```

The following commands I tried:

```
C:\blat>Blat C:/message.txt -to yyya@xxxaa.com -server outlook
.office365.com
```

Do I need to change the parameters that I am supplying?

Answer (score 3):

BLAT doesn't support SSL or TLS, and thus will not work with Office 365's SMTP server (smtp.office365.com). There are other command-line utilities you can use, instead - see [7 Command Line Utilities to Easily Send Email Using SMTP](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/sending-email-using-command-line-useful-for-downtime-alert-notification/).

If you really want to stick with BLAT, see Microsoft's [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx) for alternate options. You will not be able to do **SMTP client submission**, but the others can work - depending on your setup.